# e2e testing angularjs with protractor (protractor interactive mode brakes)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, protractor

I am learning protractor for e2e testing angularjs and having some difficulties getting things going.

Since I am new to this framework, Im following some tutorials like https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-protractor-interactive.

watching the tutorial I see that he checks if an element has been successfully found by **tabbing*.

#### 0:56 during the tutorial, after he puts element(by.tagName("button")) and he *presumably* tabs to see further options available to the button found. he doesn't tell you how he did it actually or if he tabs or not but I am guessing he's tabbing to check if newly found elements gets new available options

I gave tries too.

I made a button and input field as he did and ran into interactive mode.

```
element(by.tagName("button")).click()
```

did fine for me. it clicked the button on index.html.

However, I cannot check if the element has been found before clicking it. That means I cannot see click option by tabbing when I am done typing to the point element(by.tagName("button")).

[image: a busy cat]

#### there's more. Trying to gain access to 'click' option on command prompt kills command prompt and makes it unresponsive. I have to force quit command prompt and restart. (The pic I uploaded showing you unresponsive command prompts if you do 'b.c' then tab.)

I found it inefficient to rerun specs just to check if element has been found every time.

I would really appreciate if someone can let me know the right solution to this problems.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was fixed [6 days ago](https://github.com/angular/protractor/commit/1a4eea4eb89362822dc86be6904c1ddfba95661e) and is not yet [released](https://github.com/angular/protractor/releases).

So you can wait for Protractor > 1.3.1 or start using master branch.

#### How to install Protractor from master branch

In case you need `sudo` and using Protractor globally installed:

```
sudo npm -g install git://github.com/angular/protractor#master
```

I prefer to setup a NodeJS project with package.json and point to an specific Protractor version or commit, for better control:

```
npm init
npm install --save git://github.com/angular/protractor#ed1c75c7
mkdir -p bin
# some handy shortcuts
ln -s ../node_modules/.bin/protractor bin/p
ln -s ../node_modules/protractor/bin/elementexplorer.js bin/e
# elementexplorer sample usage
bin/e https://angularjs.org/
# Protractor binary sample usage
bin/p your-config.js
```