# Protractor - Identifying Ui-Sref link

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, selenium, protractor

I am trying to identify the links on the following html by the following. I have installed linkUiSref by using npm. But i am still getting object has no method linkUisref. Please advise.

element(by.linkUiSref(element(by.css('#monitoring-tab > ul > li:nth-child(2) > a'))))

```
    <nav id="monitoring-tab" class="pure-menu pure-menu-open pure-menu-horizontal ng-scope">
  <ul>
    <li ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" ng-hide="hideTab.now" class="pure-menu-selected">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.real-time" href="#/monitoring/real-time">
        Now
      </a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" class="">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.day" href="#/monitoring/historical/day">
      Day</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" class="">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.month" href="#/monitoring/historical/month">
      Month</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" class="">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.year" href="#/monitoring/historical/year">
      Year</a>
    </li>
    <li ui-sref-active="pure-menu-selected" class="">
      <a ui-sref="app.monitoring.historical.lifetime" href="#/monitoring/historical/lifetime">
      Lifetime</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usage:

```
by.linkUiSref(toState, [parentElement]).
```

> toState is a String that represents a ui-router state.

You're passing an `ElementFinder` instead of a `String` ... so do:

```
$('#monitoring-tab').element(by.linkUiSref('app.monitoring.historical.month'));
```

Can also do:

```
$('#monitoring-tab').element(by.linkText('Month'));
```

Comment: Thank you Leo. I am still getting there is no method called linkUiSref wheen I use the #1. #2, am getting wrong css selector. Not sure what is wrong

Comment: Make sure you `require('protractor-linkuisref-locator')(protractor);` within your onPrepare block.

Comment: idk why you get wrong css selector on #2, try upgrading Protractor to latest.

Comment: I have the latest protractor only.Also,I know what the issue is for #1.  Although, I installed the module, I am getting no module found message.When I installed npm install protractor-linkuisref-locator -- This is what I got. From this, I cannot really tell whether it is failure or success npm WARN package.json jasmine@2.0.1 No README data
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No description
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No repository field.
npm WARN package.json node@0.0.0 No README data
protractor-linkuisref-locator@1.0.0 node_modules\protractor-linkuisref-locator

Comment: WARN are warnings, so no errors there. You will need to stop using Protractor globally, more info on that here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26240871/511069

Comment: Got it.I am using windows in my new company and struggling to install the modules. I spent half a day looking around npm modules to see where protractor was and couldn't find any.I will try the option you mentioned in the other post and ask you if i still need help.Thank you

Comment: I was able to install it locally for the project. However, still #1 and #2 don't work. It says css selector is invalid. I have reached out to dev and asked them to include some identifier for me to identify better.Thanks a bunch for your help. In the meantime, do you have any recommendation on getting to know this framework better? I worked on it for little while back and coming back to it just now. Any help is much appreciated.